# angularjs ng-class with different conditions

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have a view which shows data and i want to add another class on the list items in my view.

```
<input type="text" class="filter" placeholder="search..." ng-model="search">
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items | filter:search | orderBy:'date'">
        {{ date }} {{ item.heading }}<button ng-click="deleteItem(item.ID)"><i class='icon-trash'></i></button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

i have a variables called *item.date* and i want to compare it to another variables *today*. Here is the logic:

```
if (item.date - today <= 0) 
    apply class1 
if else (item.date - today > 0 && item.date - today <= 3)
    apply class2
and so on
```

how can i achieve this with angular?
can i put this logic directly into my view or do i need to define it in my controller?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since you have a bit heavy comparisons to make, I would suggest moving it inside a function rather than having it in HTML:

```
<li ng-class="getClass(item.date)" 
    ng-repeat="item in items | filter:search | orderBy:'date'">
```

JS:

```
$scope.getClass = function(date){
    /* comparison logic here*/
    /* returs class name as string */
}
```

Comment: I think you can use `ng-class` and get rid of the `{{}}`.

Comment: @Yann Yeah no point in using `class` attr when angular provides `ng-class`. I have updated my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I think you can use `ng-class` like this:

**HTML**

```
<li ng-class="{'class1': item.date - today <= 0, 'class2': (item.date - today > 0 && item.date - today <= 3)}"></li>
```

OR moving it inside a function like this:

**HTML**

```
<li ng-class="getClass(item.date)"></li>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.getClass = function(date){
    return {'class1': item.date - today <= 0, 'class2': (item.date - today > 0 && item.date - today <= 3)};
}
```